# pandas.read_excel() outputs 'OverflowError: date value out of range' while no date column exists

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I am trying to import a large excel file (400k x 40) to a Pandas DataFrame. While it works well on my local machine it breaks when ported to a linux server with Python=3.7, Pandas=1.2.4 and Openpyxl=3.0.7. Locally I have slightly older packages. I have tried all constelations of parameters regarding types and dates:

```
df = pd.read_excel(fpath)
df = pd.read_excel(fpath, dtype=str, parse_dates=['the_only_actual_date_column']) # all dates are within 2017
df = pd.read_excel(fpath, dtype={k:str for k in column_names})
df = pd.read_excel(fpath, converters={k:str for k in column_names})
```

but nothing worked, I am always getting the same error:

`OverflowError: date value out of range`

I suspect that somewhere a random cell is treated as a date but how is it possible that the date value is a concern if I declare to treat everything as a string? The same happens even if I specify `usecols` to only one column which is definitely not a date.

Edit: full error message

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OverflowError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-d38de141bf91> in <module>
----> 1 fu = pd.read_excel(fpath, nrows=10)

/opt/tljh/user/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    297                 )
    298                 warnings.warn(msg, FutureWarning, stacklevel=stacklevel)
--> 299             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    300 
    301         return wrapper

/opt/tljh/user/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py in read_excel(io, sheet_name, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skiprows, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, parse_dates, date_parser, thousands, comment, skipfooter, convert_float, mangle_dupe_cols, storage_options)
    365             skipfooter=skipfooter,
    366             convert_float=convert_float,
--> 367             mangle_dupe_cols=mangle_dupe_cols,
    368         )
    369     finally:

/opt/tljh/user/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py in parse(self, sheet_name, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, converters, true_values, false_values, skiprows, nrows, na_values, parse_dates, date_parser, thousands, comment, skipfooter, convert_float, mangle_dupe_cols, **kwds)
   1188             convert_float=convert_float,
   1189             mangle_dupe_cols=mangle_dupe_cols,
-> 1190             **kwds,
   1191         )
   1192 

/opt/tljh/user/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py in parse(self, sheet_name, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, dtype, true_values, false_values, skiprows, nrows, na_values, verbose, parse_dates, date_parser, thousands, comment, skipfooter, convert_float, mangle_dupe_cols, **kwds)
    490                 sheet = self.get_sheet_by_index(asheetname)
    491 
--> 492             data = self.get_sheet_data(sheet, convert_float)
    493             usecols = maybe_convert_usecols(usecols)
    494 

/opt/tljh/user/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_openpyxl.py in get_sheet_data(self, sheet, convert_float)
    546         data: List[List[Scalar]] = []
    547         last_row_with_data = -1
--> 548         for row_number, row in enumerate(sheet.rows):
    549             converted_row = [self._convert_cell(cell, convert_float) for cell in row]
    550             if not all(cell == "" for cell in converted_row):

/opt/tljh/user/lib/python3.7/site-packages/openpyxl/worksheet/_read_only.py in _cells_by_row(self, min_col, min_row, max_col, max_row, values_only)
     77                                  data_only=self.parent.data_only, epoch=self.parent.epoch,
     78                                  date_formats=self.parent._date_formats)
---> 79         for idx, row in parser.parse():
     80             if max_row is not None and idx > max_row:
     81                 break

/opt/tljh/user/lib/python3.7/site-packages/openpyxl/worksheet/_reader.py in parse(self)
    153                 element.clear()
    154             elif tag_name == ROW_TAG:
--> 155                 row = self.parse_row(element)
    156                 element.clear()
    157                 yield row

/opt/tljh/user/lib/python3.7/site-packages/openpyxl/worksheet/_reader.py in parse_row(self, row)
    284             self.row_dimensions[str(self.row_counter)] = attrs
    285 
--> 286         cells = [self.parse_cell(el) for el in row]
    287         return self.row_counter, cells
    288 

/opt/tljh/user/lib/python3.7/site-packages/openpyxl/worksheet/_reader.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    284             self.row_dimensions[str(self.row_counter)] = attrs
    285 
--> 286         cells = [self.parse_cell(el) for el in row]
    287         return self.row_counter, cells
    288 

/opt/tljh/user/lib/python3.7/site-packages/openpyxl/worksheet/_reader.py in parse_cell(self, element)
    205                     try:
    206                         value = from_excel(
--> 207                             value, self.epoch, timedelta=style_id in self.timedelta_formats
    208                         )
    209                     except ValueError:

/opt/tljh/user/lib/python3.7/site-packages/openpyxl/utils/datetime.py in from_excel(value, epoch, timedelta)
    120     if 0 < value < 60 and epoch == WINDOWS_EPOCH:
    121         day += 1
--> 122     return epoch + datetime.timedelta(days=day) + diff
    123 
    124 

OverflowError: date value out of range
```

Comment: post some data that reproduces the issue (~10 rows should suffice). Use interval-halving to pin down the offending rows.

Comment: openpyxl provides a warning with the cell coordinates if the date is outside limits.

Comment: @PaulH thanks for the suggestion, I will take a look at providing it. The size is too big to make this multiple times in Excel. I've done it manually once and the import of only 10 lines works. Would be much easier if Pandas.read_excel() 'nrows' argument would just take the first 10rows without reading in the rest but unfortunatelly it doesn't work this way.

Comment: @CharlieClark I've seen your thread here https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl/-/issues/1670 didn't know it was already integrated - great stuff. Unfortunately the message doesn't get passed through pandas. I will work with openpyxl to analyse the file.

Comment: @CharlieClark I have tried `openpyxl.load_workbook(path)` but I am getting exactly the same as through Pandas. How can I get to the coordinates?

Answer (score 3):

if you face this issue while reading excel/csv file using pandas, then check your excel/csv file, any one or more column will have the values like #############, that means value is negative ex: (-11111) or date is too long to fit in the cell

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(file path,dtype='string') #this will convert all the column 
     type to string

or if you want to convert specific column then 

df = pd.read_excel(file path,converters={'column name':str})

change the dtype according your need 

df = pd.read_excel(fpath)
df = pd.read_excel(fpath, dtype='string')

you dont need to loop through each column to change the dtype, you can do it once
```