# Python/Pandas Error - OverflowError: date value out of range

Tags: python, excel, pandas

```
excel_file = pd.read_excel("file.xlsx", usecols=["col_name1", "col_name2"])
```

I am trying to do a simple read_excel action and keep getting this error:

> OverflowError: date value out of range

The excel file has multiple columns with date values and some of those values show up as `"#######"`; which I am fairly certain is causing the error. However, `col_name1` and `col_name2` are not among these columns.

I have tried modifying the function parameters in various ways such as:

```
parse_dates=False, dtype='string', converters={'Start Date': str,'End Date': str, "Creation Date": str})
```

Is there any way to read this sheet without having to go into the excel file itself to manipulate the data for it to work?

Comment: Try [`this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67595115/pandas-read-excel-outputs-overflowerror-date-value-out-of-range-while-no-da).

Comment: @MayankPorwal i tried all those things as shown in the second code snippet in my post

Answer (score 0):

I had to update my Pandas version lol

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).