# Python/Panda- Error: OverflowError: date value out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm having an error reading a pandas file of type excel.When I put it to pandas to read an excel file it is showing me this error in the dates, I checked the file is in iso format the dates. What should I do?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('./Inputs/fileXXX.xlsx')
```

```
c:\Users\XXXXXXXXXXX\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\_reader.py in parse_cell(self, element)
    204                     data_type = 'd'
    205                     try:
--> 206                         value = from_excel(
    207                             value, self.epoch, timedelta=style_id in self.timedelta_formats
    208                         )

c:\Users\XXXXXXXXXXX\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\utils\datetime.py in from_excel(value, epoch, timedelta)
    120     if 0 < value < 60 and epoch == WINDOWS_EPOCH:
    121         day += 1
--> 122     return epoch + datetime.timedelta(days=day) + diff
    123 
    124 

OverflowError: date value out of range
```

Answer (score 3):

For the solution of this problem, we must find the errors in our Base. So I went directly to the files in the `openpyxl` library and filtered that path:

`openpyxl/worksheet/_reader.py`

Look for this part of the code:

```
except ValueError:
                         msg = """Cell {0} is marked as a date but the serial value {1} is outside the limits for dates. The cell will be treated as an error.""".format(coordinate, value)
```

Swap for this:

```
except(OverflowError, ValueError):
                         msg = f"""Cell {coordinate} is marked as a date but the serial value {value} is outside the limits for dates. The cell will be treated as an error."""
```

After that run your Python code, to find the error in your base. That's how you can handle it.

Afterwards, our bug was checked, that we reviewed the openpyx library is bugged in version `3.0.7`.

To solve give:

```
pip install --upgrade openpyxl==3.0.9
```

To reinstall use:

```
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall openpyxl==3.0.9
```

Font:[Solution Font](https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl/-/commit/380abede17d270c10ceb0c4cdfd0219553e6fad5#c04ceda68e417510ee1c20eb4ffb09c4b374be00)

Answer (score 0):

This similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67595115/pandas-read-excel-outputs-overflowerror-date-value-out-of-range-while-no-da) looks helpful. One option is to just read in every column as strings with something like this:

```
df = pd.read_excel('./Inputs/fileXXX.xlsx', dtype='string')
```

Alternatively, you can choose to read only the column you know is causing the error in as a string, leaving the others be.

```
df = pd.read_excel('./Inputs/fileXXX.xlsx', converters={'date_column':str})
```

Comment: This solution is not working :(